# Impulse responses - Mean, Median or Point estimate?

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, bootstrap, vector-autoregression, impulse-response

Im thinking about what is the most reasonable way to plot impulse responses in a simple OLS VAR model independent of the identification strategy.

${Y}_t = A_1{Y}_{t-1}+ U_t$

I have learned that the response of $y_1$ in period 1 is the shock in $u_1t$.  In the following periods the reaction is a combination of the one time shock $u$ and how it interact with the Variables $Y_t$: Reaction of $y_1$ in Period 2 is $u_1$*$a_1$ etc. (see Lütkepohl 2007 p.52). For the construction of the confidence intervalls a bootstrap is used.

This procedure would be a  "point estimate".

Diving deeper in Econometrics I found different VAR libraries which use a slighly different procedure:

1. Calculate a IRF as mentioned above.
2. Calculate the confidence intervalls with the bootstrap
3. Use the **mean** or **median** over all bootstrap samples to calculate the impulse responses.

It reminds me a little of a Bayesian approach. This could have the advantage that the irf is always within the confidence interval. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879920/r-impulse-response-function-expected-values-lie-outside-of-the-confidence-inter) could be avoided. The drawback is that I am no longer able to test the point estimator?

Can anyone confirm my thoughts? Are there significant differences between the methods or are both approaches acceptable?

Mean response
[image: Mean responses]

Point Estimator
[image: Point Estimator]

Comment: Do you mean *confidence intervals* (for parameter estimates) or *forecast intervals* (for realizations of random variables)? If the latter, you may replace the [tag:confidence-interval] tag with the [tag:prediction-interval] tag.

Comment: I mean confidence intervals. :)

Comment: Hm, could you then elaborate on *the irf is always within the confidence interval*?

Comment: Of course: I get the confidence intervalls by drawing bootstrap samples and calculate the upper and lower quantiles over all samples. When I now use the median/mean over this samples instead of my point estimates they should be, by construction, inside my confidence bands.

Comment: I added an example picture to clarify my thoughts. The Point estimator IRF is calculated by textbook, the mean response by taking the mean over the bootstrap samples

Comment: Thanks. My knowledge of VAR is getting ever more rusty. So that means impulse responses are parameters? When I think a little bit more, I gather they are just linear combinations of parameters, right?

Comment: Inside each bootstrap samples I calculate the "normal" impulse response parameters. That mean impulse responses are the mean over all bootstrap samples.